# prevent to view appear with animmation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a problem that my custom navigation bar appears for the first time with animation. I think it happens because I use auto-layout and it animates it self into the state of landscape or portrait. But I want to have a functionality, that after first time I enter the screen everything is still, and where it belongs. and after that if I turn the screen or if I  do something all the animations appears like now.

Is there a good think to omit the first animations when the view creates itself?

The animations are : labels floating from left to right. and 1 label appears as from 0px width and height it scales into 100% width and height

code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.topBar];
```

self.topbar is UIView. I have added it to block    `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{ }];` but it does not helps, everytime the view appears for the first time I have my labels floating from left to right.

Comment: Could you please add some code or images so that we can understand the scenario?

Comment: @Nik Hi, The scenario is that I have 3 labels in navigation Bar which is UI view. and it appears for the first time animated floating from left to right.  The UI view is created in interfacebuilder, and it links just actions, But I have to support landscape and portrait orientation which shrinks one constraint to 50 from width/3  (It is animated) but the first animations are weird. I have no code for them :( if it is something unclear please ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I used some methods  `[self layoutIfNeeded];`  After setting the constraint. The solution is to have a method set like this:

```
- (void) yourAnimation:(BOOL)animated{
  if(animated){ 
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        //your animated code
        //[self layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
  }else{
  [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
            //your stuff without animation
        }];
  }
}
```